# I have encountered with this issue and I have correct gui elements

Tags: python, pywinauto

This issue I already used correct elements and class used by printing identification of class program apptitle [Error]this error shows:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ22H.png)

```
from pywinauto import Application, findwindows
import pywinauto.application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

path=r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hardware change\hard-disk-serial-number-changer-1.0-installer.exe"
apptitle="Hard Disk Serial Number Changer"

try:
    app=Application(backend="uia").connect(title=apptitle)

except findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
    print("App is not connected")

try:
    app=Application(backend="uia").start(path)
    app.wait_until("ready")
    edit_control = app.child_window(auto_id="460840", control_type="Edit")
    print("Edit control found:", edit_control)
    
    print("Control rectangle:", edit_control.rectangle())
    edit_control.click()

    app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=1, timeout=5, usage_interval=1)

    send_keys('^a')
    send_keys('{{BACKSPACE}}')

except pywinauto.application.AppStartError:
    print("Directory not found or app is not specified")

except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
    print("You have included incorrect gui elements")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously incorrect usage: `app.wait_until("ready")`

Application object represents a process, not a window. You must create search criteria (like a locator in Selenium) for top level window:

```
app.window(title=apptitle).wait("ready")
edit_control_spec = app.window(title=apptitle).child_window(auto_id="460840", control_type="Edit")
print("Edit control found:", edit_control_spec.wrapper_object())
```

In the future releases `.wrapper_object()` will be renamed to `.find()`.

But when you call `edit_control_spec.click()`, it calls `.wrapper_object()` implicitly and calls method `.click()` for a found wrapper.